# Check if a char in an array is a certain character

Tags: c

I am generating a random number and checking if the character contained is a certain character (i.e. 0xDB). This doesn't seem to be the correct way to do it as it seems like my if() is always false and goes to else.

How can I achieve this? Code below. Thanks!

```
if(buffer[randomNumber] == 0xDB) 
    count++;
else {
    buffer[randomNumber] = 0xDB;
    arrayChangeFlag++;
    count++;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What is the type of `buffer`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is the type of `buffer`?

I guess that it is either `signed char` or implicitly-signed `char`. The range of a signed char in most implementations is (-128,+127). `0xDB` is outside that range, so that equality test might never be true.

Try changing the type of buffer to `unsigned char`, or replacing your test with:

```
 if((unsigned char)buffer[randomNumber] == 0xDB)
```

or

```
 if(buffer[randomNumber] == (char)0xDB)
```

Answer (score 0):

If this were my code, I'd probably re-write it like this:

```
count++;
if(buffer[randomNumber] != 0xDB) {
    buffer[randomNumber] = 0xDB;
    arrayChangeFlag++;
}
```

This makes it easier to see that `count` is incremented no matter what, and makes it more clear that `buffer[randomNumber]` will be set to `0xDB` on exit from this block.

It won't fix your underlying bug though; if you're using a plain `char`, perhaps your environment uses a `signed char` (as allowed by the standard), and the *integer* `0xDB` is going to be positive while the `signed char` value represented by the *byte* `0xDB` is going to be negative. Try changing to `unsigned char buffer[]`.